# Converting Object to Double in Java

Tags: java, exception, collections, casting, double

I'm trying to deal with a lot of ClassCastExceptions in my code that are originating from a single critical point. I'll start with providing some background information for this question

I'm reading different types of values from a csv file. The following is a snapshot of the class that holds them.

```
public class Row {
private Object[] data;

public Object getAtIndex(int i)
{
    return data[i];
}
}
```

For holding the different rows of a file, I'm using a

```
ArrayList<Row> rows;
```

The **problem** lies in a function which is **supposed to return a Double[] containing values of a particular column stored in the ArrayList**. My current function looks like this

```
public Double[] getByIndex(int i)
    {
        Double[] result = new Double[rows.size()];
        String temp;
        for(int j=0;j<rows.size();j++)
        {
            temp =(String)rows.get(j).getAtIndex(i); //java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.String
            result[j]=Double.parseDouble(temp);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

This getByIndex() is throwing ClassCastExceptions when called. I'm making sure that I call this function for only those columns which are expected to have Double values. 
Is there any other way to facilitate this Object to Double conversion. My progress is stalled because of this problem.
Please help.

Comment: Your row already contains a double on one of your calls, and you are trying to cast it to a String. How do you populate your rows?

Comment: Thanks everyone! Special thanks to @vizier for a KISS-compliant solution :) 

I never knew responses on StackOverflow are so quick. Makes me want to be active in such a vibrant community. You guys rock!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of

```
temp =(String)rows.get(j).getAtIndex(i); //java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.String
result[j]=Double.parseDouble(temp);
```

just use the following:

```
        result[j]=(Double)rows.get(j).getAtIndex(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

To be somewhat more bulletproof I would combine the answers by esej and vizier... (but only if this wasn't a performance bottle neck!)

```
Object temp = rows.get(j).getAtIndex(i);
if (temp instanceof Double) {
   result[j]=(Double)rows.get(j).getAtIndex(i);
} else {
  try {
    temp = String.valueOf(rows.get(j).getAtIndex(i));
    result[j]= Double.parseDouble(temp);
  } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    // logging and recovery code goes here, or rethrow as an exception you can handle.
  }
}
```

If this is the performance bottleneck of the application then by all means go with what vizier said :)

Comment: Object temp =(String)rows.get(j).getAtIndex(i);

is throwing the same ClassCastException again

Comment: Yeah, Gus made a typo (remove the full "(String)" of the first line). Otherwise I like his/her answer since it includes a try-catch. The right solution is probably somewhere else in your code (where you populate the Row class - and redefining that class some, it is kinda strange to populate it totally untyped imho.)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
String.valueOf(rows.get(j).getAtIndex(i))
```

Or: (If your rows only contains Double, but then you should probably declare it as such.)

```
Double temp;
for(int j=0;j<rows.size();j++)
{
    temp =(Double)rows.get(j).getAtIndex(i);
    result[j]=Double.parseDouble(temp);
```

You are excplicitly casting something to a String, when that something isn't a String the cast will fail (String is final in Java). The key to the right thing is what you put into the rows, is it only Doubles?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of problems with what you're attempting.

First and foremost, you shouldn't need a temporary string in order to get to a Double.  That's definite code smell, indicating that something's gone wrong.

From the looks of things, you should be able to do that cast directly:

```
result[j]=(Double)rows.get(j).getAtIndex(i);
```

<sup>This is the suggestion @vizier made</sup>

Secondly, if you *did* want to get a string from some object that is not a string, you should use either `Object.toString()` or `String.valueOf`.  Simply casting a value in hopes that it's a string is almost never a good idea (unless you're certain that it will be a String).  In you're case, you're expecting Doubles, so `String.valueOf(Double)` would work.